# How to get the Windows version of every machine on a domain in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We are doing a OS patching cycle and we are trying to determine what machines on our network are running what versions of Windows, although we have reports, they say different things ergo we don't know which report is accurate so i thought that using PowerShell to query the information would be the most accurate way to get this info

I'm not sure how to get that info with just 'Get' commands however, it would also need to be outputted to a file that can be filtered and searched

Comment: Is WinRM / PowerShell remoting configured on all the machines? Are they always on?

Comment: _we have reports_ Can we see some of that? How do you generate these reports?

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) --- [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), You query is common, lots of web examples.

Comment: ['about PowerShell Remoting'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27about+PowerShell+Remoting%27&t=h_&ia=web) or just push out a scheduled task with a call the OS ```ver``` command and write that back to a central file on a remove vile server.

Answer (score 0):

you can query Active Directory:

```
#Get OS info from AD
$data = get-adcomputer -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=*)" -property operatingSystemVersion
#Export data
$osInfo | select-object -Property samaccountname,operatingSystemVersion | export-csv C:\tmp\osInfo.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

If you need more infos CIM/WMI is your friend, e.g.:

```
#get all computers that have logged on to domain within the last 50 days, and ping machines to ensure they are available
$lastLogon = (Get-Date).AddDays(-50).ToFileTime()
$computers = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter (lastlogontimestamp<=$lastLogon) -Properties dnshostname
$computers = $computers | ?{Test-connection $_.dnshostname -Quiet}

#get os info from machines
$osInfo = get-cimInstance -query "Select version,buildnumber from win32_operatingsystem" -ComputerName $computers

#export data
$osInfo | select-object -Property psComputerName,version,buildnumber | export-csv C:\tmp\osInfo.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

If WinRM is not configured on the target machines get-cimInstance won't work, you may then try the good old wmi:

```
$osInfo = Get-WmiObject -query "Select version,buildnumber from win32_operatingsystem" -ComputerName $computers
```